# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() PDO/SQLServer

Tags: php, pdo, sql-server-2014, odbc

Saludos, tengo un código que me esta dando problemas con un `foreach` y no he logrado su correcto funcionamiento, es una consulta a una base de datos `SQLServer` con PDO ODBC, He probado las consultas por separado en PHP y no da problemas (Estas consultas deben ser dinámicas ha raíz de los resultados de una estática), he probado las consultas directamente en el motor de base de datos y los resultados son los esperados el problema surge en el php, espero me puedan ayudar.

**PHP**

```
function cargosUsuarios(){

    $mssql=conectarBDSOF();
    $sql="SELECT codiCC, DescCC FROM v_TPersonalB WHERE codiCC LIKE '20%' AND mes<>'' GROUP BY DescCC, codiCC";
    $cargosNo=array('002','006','009','010','027','67','001','021','016','011','005','038','054','76','003','007','62','81');
    $tablaCC='<table class="table" style="margin-bottom:0;">';
    $tablaCC.='<tbody>';
    foreach ($mssql->query($sql) as $row) {

        $sqlCARGOS="SELECT CarNom, carCod FROM v_TPersonalB WHERE codiCC='".trim($row["codiCC"])."' AND mes<>'' AND carCod<>'' GROUP BY CarNom, carCod";
        if("40-04"!=$row["codiCC"]){
                $cargos='<table class="table" style="margin-bottom:0;">';
                $cargos.='<tbody>';
                echo $sqlCARGOS;
                foreach ($mssql->query($sqlCARGOS) as $row2) {  // AQUI SURGE EL PROBLEMA           
                    if(in_array($row2["carCod"], $cargosNo)){}else{
                        $cargos.='<tr>';
                        $cargos.='<td>'.$row2["CarNom"].'</td>';
                        $cargos.='<td><input type="checkbox" name="cargosUsusarios[]" value="'.$row["codiCC"].'/'.$row2["carCod"].'"></td>';
                        $cargos.='</tr>';
                    }                   
                }
                $cargos.='</tbody>';
                $cargos.='</table>';

                $tablaCC.='<tr>';
                $tablaCC.='<td style="vertical-align:middle;">'.$row["DescCC"].'</td>';
                $tablaCC.='<td colspan="2">'.$cargos.'</td>';
                $tablaCC.='</tr>';
        }
    }
    $tablaCC.='</tbody>';
    $tablaCC.='</table>';
    echo $tablaCC;  
}
```

Comment: Es muy probable que el problema se deba a la consulta `$sqlCARGOS`, ya sea porque no devuelve ningún registro o porque es inválida. Es difícil saber exactamente cual es le motivo saber porque no has compartido todo lo necesario para deducirlo.

Comment: en cual de los dos foreach te marca el problema?

Comment: @Marcos `$sqlCARGOS` es la consulta problematica pero la he probado directo en el motor de base de datos y trae resultados, ¿que mas puedo agregar? puse todo el codigo, @Andrés es en el segundo `foreach`

Comment: @Kevin, intenta hacer un `echo gettype($mssql->query($sqlCARGOS))`, justo debajo de `$sqlCARGOS="SELECT CarNom...`, de esa forma al menos sabrás que es lo que esta devolviendo.

Comment: @Marcos me arroja `boolean` y el ultimo `object` que es la unica consulta que se ejecuta

Comment: @Marcos le hice un `try` con `$mssql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);` y me dice que la conecion esta ocupada con otro hstmt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que encontré utilizando

```
try{
$coneccion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
//codigo
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

> La conexión está ocupada con los resultados de otro hstmt

por lo cual la solución que se me ocurrió (Desconozco si hay otra forma) fue crear 2 `array()`

```
$codiCC=array();
$DescCC=array();
```

los cuales los lleno en el primer `foreach`

```
$i=1;
foreach ($mssql->query($sql2) as $row) {
    $codiCC[$i]=$row["codiCC"];
    $DescCC[$i]=$row["DescCC"];
    $i++;
}
```

de esta forma libero la coneccion, luego recorro los `array` y realizo las consultas dinámicas a la bd

```
foreach ($codiCC as $key => $value) {//Recorro un array

        $sqlCARGOS="SELECT CarNom, carCod FROM v_TPersonalB WHERE codiCC='".trim($value)."' AND mes<>'' AND carCod<>'' GROUP BY CarNom, carCod";
        if("40-04"!=$value){
                $cargos='<table class="table" style="margin-bottom:0;">';
                $cargos.='<tbody>';
                foreach ($mssql->query($sqlCARGOS) as $row2) {              
                    if(in_array($row2["carCod"], $cargosNo)){}else{
                        $cargos.='<tr>';
                        $cargos.='<td>'.$row2["CarNom"].'</td>';
                        $cargos.='<td><input type="checkbox" name="cargosUsusarios[]" value="'.$value.'/'.$row2["carCod"].'"></td>';
                        $cargos.='</tr>';
                    }                   
                }
                $cargos.='</tbody>';
                $cargos.='</table>';

                $tablaCC.='<tr>';
                $tablaCC.='<td style="vertical-align:middle;">'.$DescCC[$key].'</td>';
                $tablaCC.='<td colspan="2">'.$cargos.'</td>';
                $tablaCC.='</tr>';
        }
    }
```

al haber realizado estas modificaciones el código final y obtengo el resultado deseado es:

```
$mssql=conectarBDSOF();
    $sql="SELECT codiCC, DescCC FROM v_TPersonalB WHERE codiCC LIKE '20%' AND mes<>'' GROUP BY DescCC, codiCC";
    $sql1="SELECT codiCC, DescCC FROM v_TPersonalB WHERE codiCC LIKE '40%' AND mes<>'' GROUP BY DescCC, codiCC";
    $sql2="SELECT codiCC, DescCC FROM v_TPersonalB WHERE codiCC LIKE '10%' AND mes<>'' GROUP BY DescCC, codiCC";
    $cargosNo=array('002','006','009','010','027','67','001','021','016','011','005','038','054','76','003','007','62','81');
    $cuerpoProcesos="";
    $cuerpoAdministrativos="";
    $cuerpoProduccion="";
    $tablaCC='<table class="table" style="margin-bottom:0;">';
    $tablaCC.='<tbody>';
    // MODIFICADO
    $codiCC=array();
    $DescCC=array();
    $i=1;
    foreach ($mssql->query($sql2) as $row) {// LLENO LOS ARRAY
        $codiCC[$i]=$row["codiCC"];
        $DescCC[$i]=$row["DescCC"];
        $i++;
    }
    foreach ($codiCC as $key => $value) { // RECORRO LOS ARRAY

        $sqlCARGOS="SELECT CarNom, carCod FROM v_TPersonalB WHERE codiCC='".trim($value)."' AND mes<>'' AND carCod<>'' GROUP BY CarNom, carCod";
        if("40-04"!=$value){
                $cargos='<table class="table" style="margin-bottom:0;">';
                $cargos.='<tbody>';
                foreach ($mssql->query($sqlCARGOS) as $row2) {              
                    if(in_array($row2["carCod"], $cargosNo)){}else{
                        $cargos.='<tr>';
                        $cargos.='<td>'.$row2["CarNom"].'</td>';
                        $cargos.='<td><input type="checkbox" name="cargosUsusarios[]" value="'.$value.'/'.$row2["carCod"].'"></td>';
                        $cargos.='</tr>';
                    }                   
                }
                $cargos.='</tbody>';
                $cargos.='</table>';

                $tablaCC.='<tr>';
                $tablaCC.='<td style="vertical-align:middle;">'.$DescCC[$key].'</td>';
                $tablaCC.='<td colspan="2">'.$cargos.'</td>';
                $tablaCC.='</tr>';
        }
    }
    // FIN DE MODIFICACIONES
    $tablaCC.='</tbody>';
    $tablaCC.='</table>';
    echo $tablaCC;
```